# Function to properly escape dynamic SOSL input

Tags: sosl, escape, dynamic-sosl

I have a page that allows users to specify a search term that then gets put into a SOSL Query.  Obviously I'm escaping single quotes to prevent injection, but certain input still cause my code to crash.  Has anyone written a function to properly escape SOSL terms?

**Code:**

```
String terms = 'test 3 -';
String searchquery = 'FIND {'+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(terms) +'} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ';
searchQuery += 'Issue__kav(KnowledgeArticleId, Title, Summary '
searchQuery += 'WHERE Language = \'en_US\' AND PublishStatus = \'Online\'); 
search.query(searchquery);
```

**Compiled SOSL:**

```
FIND {test 3 -} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
Issue__kav(KnowledgeArticleId, Title, Summary
WHERE Language = 'en_US' AND PublishStatus = 'Online')
```

**Error:**

> System.QueryException: line 1:13 mismatched character '-' expecting
>   '}'

Comment: see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm - the '-' is a reserved token and must be escaped by backslash

Comment: @crop1645 Yes, I understand why its happening.  I'm wondering if someone has already come up with a efficient function to escape these characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had to work on this problem too. I took a slightly different approach and let regular expressions do the bulk of the effort via the [Matcher.replaceAll( string )](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) method instead of looping and substringing myself.

The gist of my approach is below. For **full comments**, **explanation**, and **unit tests** please see [my github repo](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-escape-sosl).

```
public String escapeSosl( String text ) {

    // handle single quotes
    String escapedText = String.escapeSingleQuotes( text ) ;

    // remove reserved logical operators
    escapedText = escapedText.replaceAll( '(?i)( AND NOT | AND | OR )', ' ' );

    // match special characters to escape
    Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile( '(\\?|\\&|\\||\\!|\\{|\\}|\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)|\\^|\\~|\\*|\\:|\\"|\\+|\\-)' );
    Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher( escapedText );

    // escape special characters
    escapedText = myMatcher.replaceAll( '\\\\\\\\$1' );

    // collapse extra whitespace
    escapedText = escapedText.replaceAll( '( )+', ' ' ).trim();

    return escapedText;
}
```

I used the `String.escapeSingleQuotes(text)` method to handle the single quotes. I could not get it to work via regular expressions, I always ended up with too few or too many extra slashes `\`.

If the original input contains itself slashes `\` then that may cause issues. Like the single quotes, I had issues getting the regular expression and replacement to yield the correct number of escaping slashes. As such, my code does not support trying to escape `\` from the original input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not great with Regex but I decided I'd just have to write my own.  Everything works well except I couldn't get single quotes to escape properly.  I added them to the regex (using `\\\'`) but SOSL still complained even though it was escaped just the same as the others.  I just decided removed them instead.
If anyone can improve upon this, I'll mark your answer.

```
   public static String escapeSOSLTerm(String term){
        system.debug(term);
        term = term.replace('\'', '');
        system.debug(term);
        Pattern reservedPattern = pattern.compile('[\\?&\\|!{}\\[\\]\\(\\)\\^~\\*:\\\"\\+-]');
        Matcher myMatcher = reservedPattern.matcher(term);
        List<Integer> escapeIndexs = new List<Integer>();
        while(true){
            if(myMatcher.find()){
                escapeIndexs.add(myMatcher.start());
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        escapeIndexs.sort();
        for(Integer i = escapeIndexs.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
            Integer escapeIndex = escapeIndexs[i];
            term = term.substring(0, escapeIndex) + '\\\\' + term.substring(escapeIndex);
        }
        return term; 
    }
```

Comment: Hi does SOSL work in the first place with a special character?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you, but on special character like -. I got it to work eventually,try this out :

```
    String terms = 'test 3 -';
    String searchquery = 'FIND \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(terms) + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ';
    searchQuery += 'Issue__kav(KnowledgeArticleId, Title, Summary ';
    searchQuery += 'WHERE Language = \'en_US\' AND PublishStatus = \'Online\'); 
     search.query(searchquery);
```

The above code will work not only for the single quote, but for all the reserve char.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I tried using the code from NSJonas but that did not work for me. Sorry, I have forgotten exactly what the prob was but I ended up writing my own version. I couldn't get it working just using a regex because replacing strings with backslashes plus the original content just wasn't behaving like it should (IMHO). In any case, the following is working OK. Note that one thing I have done is strip out any backslashes from the original input. This means you cannot search on backslashes. Given my use case is vetting end user input and none of our data contains that character, I don't care about that. Other than that, the code escapes special characters that you specify with a backslash and the SOSL executes fine.

```
/*
 * @Description: Properly escape input for a SOSL query so that it's "safe" and you don't get query exceptions if user enters a special char
 * @param term: the raw search term submitted from user input
 * @returns: the escaped string, possibly an empty string if there are no acceptable characters in the input
 */
public static String escapeSOSLTerm(String term) {
    // exclude * and ? if you want your users to use wild cards
    final String specialChars = '& | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \'';

    // get rid of all backslashes from the input term
    String cleansedTerm = term.replaceAll('\\\\', '');
    for (String sc: specialChars.split(' ')) {
        cleansedTerm = cleansedTerm.replaceAll('\\' + sc, '\\\\' + sc);
    }
    return cleansedTerm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have updated @NSjonas code to escape Backslash character also.

```
public static String escapeSOSLTerm(String term){
    term = String.escapeSingleQuotes(term.replace('\'', '\\'));
    Pattern reservedPattern = pattern.compile('[\\?&\\|!{}\\[\\]\\(\\)\\^~\\*:\\\"\\+-]');
    Matcher myMatcher = reservedPattern.matcher(term);
    List<Integer> escapeIndexs = new List<Integer>();
    while(true){
        if(myMatcher.find()){
            escapeIndexs.add(myMatcher.start());
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    escapeIndexs.sort();
    for(Integer i = escapeIndexs.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
        Integer escapeIndex = escapeIndexs[i];
        term = term.substring(0, escapeIndex) + '\\' + term.substring(escapeIndex);
    }
    return term; 
}
```

You can use this to escape Backslash Character.

**String.escapeSingleQuotes(term.replace('\'', '\\'));**

**where "term" is the search string.**